# How to position an image shown on onmouseover in HTML

Tags: html, image, onmouseover

I have an image that pops up a second image on the onmouseover event. I need this second image (which is larger) to be positioned absolutely (e.g., at 10,20) without affecting the position of the first image.

I am trying to do this in HTML only.

This is my code:

```
<img src="readmore.png" onmouseover="this.src='info.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='readmore.png'"/>
```

Comment: On mouse over you're changing the source of existing image. I'd use two seperate `<img>` for this..

Comment: What would the code be for that then?

Comment: This can't be done in HTML only. You are using onmouseover and onmouseout, this is javascript. Rather than changing the image on mouseover, would it be more efficient to have the second image hidden and positioned, then display that on mouseover, and hide it on mouseout.

Comment: @BradFaircloth it can be done using css only ;)

Comment: @user3502158 please show some effort, You didn't even try to do anything with two seperate images, did you..? **[What Have You Tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)** as far as i know, SO is not the place where people simply write the code for you...

Comment: @TilwinJoy You are right... but thought that would just confuse it more. Just wanted to point out to the OP that he was using JS not HTML so it may help as he looks for an answer.

Comment: Sorry, javascript is correct. What I was trying to say was the code needs to be inline as I am inserting it into an HTML section in a slider.

Comment: I am not that familiar with HTML and JS. I have searched the web but not found how to set the x and y position parameters. I was hoping that it was something simple that someone would be kind enough to point out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**this.style.top** is used to change position along **Y-Axis**, **this.style.left** along **X-Axis**.

```
   <img src="readmore.png" onmouseover="this.src='info.jpg';this.style.left = '10px';
this.style.top = '50px';" onmouseout="this.src='readmore.png';this.style.left = '10px';
this.style.top = '50px';"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can add inline statements in html after every ; , but you should learn javascript too.

Comment: Thanks for this, that is exactly what I was looking for, but unfortunately it didn't work. I put the code in but still no change, it seems to ignore the style.left and style.top commands. I also just pasted this code straight into a wordpress page and also no luck.

Comment: Did you change the values onmouseover and onmousedown as I have put the same values ?

Comment: I mean change the values of style.top and style.left on each event.

Comment: Hi. Yes I did. For onmouseover I used 300px for top & left. Maybe wordpress theme (style) is overriding this? I am no expert.

Comment: And for onmouseout are you setting the previous values there?